# Segmention fault

Tags: c, server, segmentation-fault, client

I am trying to run program with shared memory. My code as below.

Producer:

```
int main() {
    const int SIZE = 4096;

    const char *name="OS";
    const char *message_0="Hello";
    const char *message_1="World";

    int fd;

    char *wsk;

    fd=shm_open(name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

    ftruncate(fd,SIZE);

    wsk=(char *)
            mmap(0,SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd , 0);

sprintf(wsk,"%s",message_0);
wsk += strlen(message_0);
sprintf(wsk,"%s",message_1);
wsk += strlen(message_1);
return 0; }
```

Consumer:

```
int main(){
const int SIZE=4096;

const char *name= "OS";

int fd;

char *wsk;

fd=shm_open(name,O_RDONLY,0666);

wsk=(char *)
        mmap(0,SIZE,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

printf("%s", (char *)wsk);

shm_unlink(name);

return 0; }
```

But I am getting segmention fault. I think it can be problem with pointers but I can't find resolve.I am using macOs.Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"But I am getting segmention fault"* - be specific. In which process? Producer ? Consumer? Both? And most importantly, *where* ? Where did your debugger point you when it broke on the segfault ? Some basic value-checking of those assumed-valid return results would probably be informative.

Comment: I got segfault in Consumer.

Comment: `snprintf(wsk, SIZE, "%s%s", message_0, message_1);` btw

Comment: And POSIX shared memory names need to start with a slash.

Comment: Note that the permissions you're using in `shm_open()` and `mmap()` in the consumer don't match. *Always* check return values for errors instead of assuming a function succeeds...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the consumer exiting with a segmentation fault is due to permissions.
`fd` is opened with `O_RDONLY` (read only), whereas `mmap` is called on fd with `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`. This causes `mmap` to error with `EACCESS` (permission denied). When a function like mmap errors, it returns a negative number. This means when you try to print `wsk`, you are trying to print a string at memory address `-1` which obviously is not possible.

Comment: Yes, when i changed PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE on PROT_READ consumer got data.

Comment: @DawidJanas in that case, please accept my answer.

Comment: I’m new user and i can’t vote yet.

Comment: I was trying do that on start but was the same problem . I will be remember about it.